# What does the potion medal do?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I just discovered the potion medal. The game's description seemed pretty vague. I've now got too much stuff to carry in all my adventure pouches. I need to decide what to carry with me and what to leave behind with the totally unstable item check lady. Help me decide. **What affect does the potion medal have?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The potion medal makes the potions that have a time limit last longer (twice as long, I think).

This includes the Guardian, Air, and Stamina potions (and their upgraded versions).

Comment: The effects are times 3, actually. So 9 minute duration instead of just 3.